# Group of Units - Maths Calculation

Tags: c#, math

I want to implement below logic :-
For every Static 20 units - Static Value should be added as 2.

Example :-
So if given 30 Units then Value should be 2 as per the above requirement. 
If i have 40 Units Result Value should be 4.

I tried this thing :-

```
Result = Total Units(30) * Static Value(2) / Fixed Unit(20);
```

It gives me result as 3. I expect Result as 2.

What formula should i apply for getting accurate results?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You didn't specify your language/environment. In many languages there is a special integer division so `5/2` is `2`. In such case you should just change the order of operations and use:

```
Result = (TotalUnits(30) / FixedUnit(20)) * StaticValue(2);
```

If your environment works with real numbers (so `5/2` is `2.5`), you should use some rounding down function, which is often called `Floor`

```
Result = Floor(TotalUnits(30) / FixedUnit(20)) * StaticValue(2);
```

Comment: I am using c# language

Comment: @Anup, in C# division on `int` or `long` or other standard integer types works the way described in formula #1 so it should be OK. Also there is [Math.Floor](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.math.floor(v=vs.110).aspx) method to work with `double` and `decimal`.